# automate the same function with array in php

Tags: php, arrays

suppose I have a function like

```
function crear($first, $second, $third, $fourth, $fifth, $sixth){
    $sixth= ($sixth > 0 ? "<span class='required'>*</span>" : "");
    if($fourth=='input'){
        echo "\t   <div class='field-box ".$third."' id='".$first."_field_box'>  \n";
        echo "\t\t <div class='display-as-box' id='".$first."_display_as_box'>".$second."  ".$sixth.":</div>  \n";
        echo "\t\t <div class='input-box' id='".$first."_input_box'> \n";
        echo "\t\t <input id='field-".$first."' name='".$first."' type='text' maxlength='".$fifth."' /> </div><div class='clear'></div>  \n";
        echo "\t   </div>\n";
    }
}
```

And I am calling it several times:

```
crear('title1', 'Title 1','odd',  'input', '50', 0 );
crear('title2', 'Title 2','even', 'input', '50', 0 );
crear('title3', 'Title 3','odd',  'input', '30', 1 );
crear('title4', 'Title 4','even', 'input', '50', 0 );
crear('title5', 'Title 5','odd',  'select', '19', 1 );
crear('title6', 'Title 6','even', 'select', '19', 0 );
```

How could I make only one call to this function passing all this data.

I was thinking to make an array but I woul have to modify the function, What would be the best way...
The only one I easily can suppose is odd and even field, the others got to be variables.

Comment: calling `crear()` several times, but defining `fill()`? If you don't want to modify the function itself, then put your data in an array, loop over the array, and call the function within the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`call_user_func_array()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). This allows you to pass an array into a function that would normally accept just a list of parameters.

So let's say your array looks like this: (based on the data in the question)

```
$input = array(
    array('title1', 'Title 1','odd',  'input', '50', 0 ),
    array('title2', 'Title 2','even', 'input', '50', 0 ),
    array('title3', 'Title 3','odd',  'input', '30', 1 ),
    array('title4', 'Title 4','even', 'input', '50', 0 ),
    array('title5', 'Title 5','odd',  'select', '19', 1 ),
    array('title6', 'Title 6','even', 'select', '19', 0 ),
);
```

you can use `call_user_func_array()` to pass the data into your function like this:

```
foreach($input as $data) {
    call_user_func_array('crear', $data);
}
```

You can find out more about `call_user_func_array()` in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Comment: +1 Nice, I was going to suggest creating another function to iterate through the array and call crear();

Comment: You might want to add the name of the func being called as first param ;)

Comment: @Crisp - heh, yep. :) good spot. Typing faster than thinking again  ;)